# How to redirect ALL requests, even index.php to go to another php file (parse.php)

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, php

Right now I have this in my nginx config:

```
location / {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ /parse.php;
}
```

Then further down:

```
location ~\.php$ {
            root /var/www/site.com/public/;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

If I browse to

> site.com/example/this

It does as it's supposed to and goes to parse.php ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is properly set to '/example/this').  The same goes for site.com/images/test.jpg, it will work as intended and pass it to the parse.php script.

However, if I got to 'site.com/another.php' it doesn't go to parse, and instead it says:

> No input file specified.

Any idea how to get this to work?  I removed the try_files clause and still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if anyone is wondering, this is the solution, simply merge both location blocks together then add break; to the rewrite forcing everything to go to the php script.

For some reason when both blocks are separate, the first location (which specifies that everything should be rewritten to parse.php) gets overridden by the second location (targeting php only files) and somehow reverts the request back to the original php file instead of parse.php as per the rewrite.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /parse.php break;

    root /var/www/site.com/public/;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

This will effectively parse every single request to your parse.php for the given server{} block.

Now you can determine the original request via $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; in your parse.php script and do whatever you want to from there on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need the rewrite rule because every request is sent to `parse.php`. A regex is slow. You may also try this:

```
location / {

    root /var/www/site.com/public;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/parse.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME  parse.php;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: I also removed `fastcgi_split_path_info` line because it's not needed without the `rewrite` rule. By default the $request_uri will be passed into php without any modification. It's cleaner this way.

Answer (score 0):

$uri are just for assets support, images and static files will be served directly without being passed to parse.php if they are found, otherwise it will be passed to parse.php

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /parse.php$request_uri;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```